# Unity3D Switching between two cameras depending on zoom level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble with a feature I'm trying to get working in my Unity3D project.

This consists of two game cameras a Third Person Camera and a RTS Camera, with a Camera Manager to handle switching between the two.

Both camera's have a public variable `currentDistance` so the manager can handle switching between different modes depending on the distance the camera is from the user.

For example if the user in Third person mode zooms out past 9.5 (max being 10) then the thirdperson camera is disabled and the RTS one enabled.

or for RTS to Third person mode the RTS camera has to be zoomed in to > 48.f

**In order to switch back to 3rd person from RTS mode the user has to zoom down to 48.0f. this is where the problem occurs as the camera's flick back and forth between enabled and disabled.**

I understand this is because the camera's last positions are still within the switch threshold so when either camera activates it triggers the switch, **but what I cannot understand is the logic I need in place in order to stop this happening**. I tried simply resetting the height or distance of each camera but this has the effect of keeping me stuck in whichever camera I happen to be in.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CameraManager : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject thirdpersonCamera;
public GameObject rtsCamera;

private WoWCamera thirdPersoncam;
private RTSCam rtscam;


public float RTS_MODE_THRESHOLD = 9.5f;
public float THIRD_PERSON_MODE_THRESHOLD = 48.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    thirdpersonCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MainCamera");
    rtsCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("RTSCam");

    thirdPersoncam = thirdpersonCamera.GetComponent<WoWCamera> ();
    rtscam = rtsCamera.GetComponent<RTSCam> ();
    //disable RTS cam by default, only activate it when the user zooms out past the  RTS_MODE_THRESHOLD
    rtsCamera.SetActive (false);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    int cameraID = DetermineActiveCamera ();
    if (cameraID == 1 && thirdPersoncam.currentDistance > RTS_MODE_THRESHOLD) {


            //player is in third person mode and  has zoomed out switch to RTS Cam


            //todo: need to reset cameras distance so it doesnt flip between them
            rtscam.ResetHeight();
            //thirdPersoncam.currentDistance = 8.0f;
            thirdpersonCamera.SetActive (false);
            rtsCamera.SetActive (true);

    }else if (cameraID == 2 && rtscam.currentHeight < THIRD_PERSON_MODE_THRESHOLD) {
        Debug.Log ("rts cam distance " + rtscam.currentHeight +  " and  threshold " + THIRD_PERSON_MODE_THRESHOLD);
            //player is in RTS mode and has zoomed in switch to Third person camera
            rtsCamera.SetActive (false);
            thirdpersonCamera.SetActive (true);

    }

}

//return 1 for thirdperosn camera 2 for rts, 0 for niether
int DetermineActiveCamera()
{
    if (thirdpersonCamera.activeInHierarchy != false) {
        return 1;
    } else if (rtsCamera.activeInHierarchy != false) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
 }
```

Sorry for the long winded question, I just wanted to provide as much information as I could.

Edit: Just like to add as there seems to be some confusion, I do have *ONE* script for controlling which camera is active at any one time. The difference being each Camera has its own script for controlling how they react to key presses and a public currentDistance variable. (Because an RTS cam only needs to measure how high it is above the player, the 3rd person camera needs to measure how far back it is) 
Thanks

Comment: You should try to keep a grey zone in between the 2 triggers, to prevent flicking back and forth. Or alternatively introduce a cooldown on the switch, all though this can negatively affect the user experience.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, but this is where my issue lies. I cannot see how logic like this would work, For example if I made a "buffer" zone at 8.0f then assume the Thirdperson cam is currently at 8.0f, 9.0f being the trigger, I'll still need to zoom out to 9.0f in order to trigger the switch, which is fine but as soon as I try to re-enter third person I'll *still* be at 9.0f which will trigger the switch again?

Comment: FTR you actually must use one script only to control both cameras, in a situation like this.  I hope it helps!